# Will previous technical problems with eTA cause me issues now?

Tags: canada, eta

On 19 August 2015, I applied for an eTA on the cic.gc.ca website. I encountered technical difficulties when applying. I contacted customer support, who suggested I try reprocessing the application (I think, but am not sure, that it was still cost-free at the time). The eTA was finally approved, but the system registered my Italian passport only as AA, not as AA0123456. (Basically, it forgot about the digits.)

Nonetheless, I was not fussed—this was before eTAs became mandatory. On 23 August 2015 I flew to Canada, which I left when my vacation ended on 1 September 2015.

Months after I returned home, I received emails from cic.gc.ca stating that the passport number was incorrect and urging me to correct it. At first I was suspicious ("Is this genuine?" After all I had already gotten back home), so I contacted customer service again, who kind of confirmed the issue by copying and pasting the same text. I attempted to correct it, but to no avail. Further emails to cic.gc.ca went unanswered. I kept receiving the same email (Correct your passport number) years after I ended my trip. However, I had no plans to travel to Canada, and the passport subsequently expired in 2018, so I just let it be.

My questions are:

1. Will my previous technical difficulties cause me problems, either technical or with immigration, if I apply for an eTA now with a new passport (of a new nationality)?
2. When applying for an eTA now, should I include the number of the August 2015 eTA application, even though it is linked to a wrong passport number? Or just write N/A?

I have tried to check the status of that eTA on the online status check tool, and what I get is "No matches were found using the criteria provided" if I input my correct passport number. If I just input AA, I get an error message "The form could not be submitted because errors were found. Passport number - must only contain alphanumeric characters or a space."

What should I do now? I have no imminent plans to visit Canada, but would like to travel in the next couple of years, and am worried this past glitch will cause me problems, either by making my application remain stuck or worse causing me to get it declined. Should I take the issue proactively and apply even before I begin to think of a trip to Canada, so I can attempt to solve the issues well in advance? It seems that the eTA website is plagued with technical problems, which is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: not a chance they can link that new eTA to the old one. Forget about it.

Comment: So should I just write N/A when it asks for the number of previous eTAs? (Obviously I’d have to answer Yes to the question, because I did in fact apply and received an eTA.)

Comment: There's a reason I only comment and not answer. I am not sure what's best.

Answer (score 4):

> Will my previous technical difficulties cause me problems, either technical or with immigration, if I apply for an eTA now with a new passport (of a new nationality)?

Maybe.

> When applying for an eTA now, should I include the number of the August 2015 eTA application, even though it is linked to a wrong passport number? Or just write N/A?

Yes, you should answer honestly and provide as much information as you can. You also have an oppoturnity to provide additional explanation (which you should do, as you have written here).

> Should I take the issue proactively and apply even before I begin to think of a trip to Canada, so I can attempt to solve the issues well in advance?

There is a very significant likelihood that it will be simply approved. But yes, you should apply for an eTA as soon as possible. In case that the eTA is not instantly approved (within an hour), it will be reviewed by an agent and they may grant your authorization or request more information (e.g. copies of the emails you have sent them). It is not likely that you will be declined for the technical issues.

There is no way around an eTA application if you want to enter Canada unless you travel to the U.S. first and try to enter Canada by land travel or ferry.

Comment: Thank you. I have no imminent plans to travel to Canada soon, but I'll apply again sometime in October, once the summer rush of things is over and it may be easier to deal with these things. I considered getting in touch with the cic.gc.ca people, but if my previous experience is anything to go by, getting a response from them will be difficult.

Comment: Should my eTA be denied for any reason, would I be able to apply for a visa instead? The website is so confusing!

Comment: @NYCvisitor2228968 No, eTA is the "visa" for visa-free nationals seeking admission into Canada as temporary residents by air. Visa-free nationals cannot get a TRV. Denials are made by actual agents after reviewing your application, accompanied with reasons and you can re-apply. You may also submit a reconsideration request to IRCC (unlikely to succeed unless some facts included in the application were clearly ignored) or in certain circumstances, a judicial review request to the Federal Court (unlikely to succeed, and very costly).

Comment: I see. Then I guess more than an actual refusal (since CIC would have to give reasons, and I can't see how I breach any conditions for admission), my biggest risk would be that my application may remain stuck in limbo for forevermore due to tech problems... Some stories of eTA taking months do not inspire confidence.